# Find out reason for class finalization

Tags: c++, c++14, visual-studio-2019

At some point of time, a class in my C++14 project is being terminated / finalized.

However, I don't see why it is being terminated / finalized.

I would like to find out the reason / caller for this.

It looks like this:

[image]

The call stack however, doesn't tell me. Or at least I don't see why.

How could I find out why / where the class is terminated?

Comment: "_in my C++11 project_" - How? How do you maintain a C++11 project in VS2019? Does it support anything earlier than C++14?

Comment: Ooops, perhaps it's c++14...

Comment: :-) Yes, right now it is. You can change the tag. by clicking the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68868553/edit) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Options menu, under “Debugging/General”, deselect “Enable Just my code” and it’ll show you the full callstack. (You’ll likely need to restart the debugger.)